# Passing parameters to the route on button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I am new to AngularJs. I have a search box with a button which hits the route defined in the config of Angular application.

```
<div class="search-block clearfix">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search here..."  class="form-control input-sm">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" go-click="search.htm">Search</button>
    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div>
```

Adding the code snippet of route config:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    .when('/search.htm',
     {
        controller:'controllers.SearchCtrl',
        templateUrl:'/partials/search/searchPage.html'
     })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
   ....
```

Adding the directive(go-click) code as well:

```
    myApp.directive( 'goClick', function ( $location ) {
      return function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
        var path;
        attrs.$observe( 'goClick', function (val) {
        path = val;
      });
       element.bind( 'click', function () {
         scope.$apply( function () {
          $location.path( path );
      });
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Please show the route config.

Comment: I have updated the post with the route config. The control is coming inside the controller but I am not able to pass the keywords typed inside the search box as parameters to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$route` and `$routeParams` services to pass parameters to a new route.

If you change your route to:

```
.when('/search.htm/:paramName',
     {
        controller:'controllers.SearchCtrl',
        templateUrl:'/partials/search/searchPage.html'
     })
```

And redirect to `search.htm/someParam`

Then the parameter `someParam` will be available in the route's controller as the service `$routeParams` (which is an object containing the parameters) or in the `$route` service under `$route.current.params` (which is the same object).

This is covered in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route).